# Drupal 6 with mongodb, any success?

Tags: performance, database

There is a [mongodb](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) module which is in develeopment stage. As usually find MySQL as my bottleneck, wondering whether anyone has actually implemented mongodb on D6 with success? And if so what are good resources on how to implement mongodb?

Comment: No one has actually tried this?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is not a full replacement for MySQL, you still need it. You can only move certain pluggable systems to MongoDB, like sessions, watchdog and in Drupal 7 also the field storage.

Comment: I know that Berdir, just wondering whether handling some of the tables through mongodb actually has been successful implemented in D6 (regarding that the module is still in dev stage) and helped some sites get around the mysql bottleneck.